# Add multiple filterviews using values from a column of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have this Apps Script function that Adds a filterview to a sheet. I would like to use a function that creates multiple filterviews to the same sheet, using the values from columnIndex 3 to define the title, filterViewId, and filter criteria.

This is the Apps Script function that I have:

```
function AddFilterView() {  //Adds a filterview
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');  //Sheet in which filterview will be added
  var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();
  var filterSettings = {
    "filterViewId": "2",  // write a integer+32 number for the filterview Id
    "title": "2", // write a title for the filterview
    "range":{
      "sheetId": sheetId,
      "startRowIndex": 0,
      "endRowIndex": lastRow,
      "startColumnIndex": 0,
      "endColumnIndex": lastColumn
    }
  };
  var condition_value = {
    "type": "TEXT_EQ",
    "values": [{"userEnteredValue": "2"}]
  };

 filterSettings.criteria = {};

  var columnIndex = 3; // column that defines criteria [A = 0]
  filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
    'condition' : condition_value
  };
  
  var requests = [{
    "addFilterView":{
      "filter": filterSettings,
    }
  }];
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({"requests":requests}, ss.getId());  
}
```

And this is a image capture of the sheet that I am using:

[image: Image capture of the sheet that I am using]

Comment: What is your current issue? And, is the sample image the input situation? If it's so, can you provide the sample output situation as an image?